# Fetch api not able to send data from react to express

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am trying to send a object from react to express using fetch api. I have added the data to post request. the express server is unable to receive any request made to it.

React Code:

```
  const sendData = async ()=>{
    try{
      const response = await  fetch("http://localhost:4000/register",{method:"POST",mode:"cors",body:{"state":"its working"}});
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect started");
    sendData();
  }, [user]);
```

Express code

```
app.route("/register").post((req,res)=>{
  const postData = req.body.state;
  console.log(postData);
});
```

Kindly help. I am not sure why it is not able to log anything in serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the body data to JSON before sending it in the request.

```
    const sendData = async () = {
    ...
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/register", {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ state: "its working" })
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
}
```

In your express code, you can access the state property of the request body using

```
app.route("/register").post((req, res) => {
  const postData = req.body.state;
  ...
  res.send("Received the data successfully!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In React App (frontend): add the headers property as following: `js headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` in the api call function.
In Express App (backend): add the middleware as following: `js app.use(express.json());` which help to parse the json body.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you set JSON parse on backend entry file?
- Try sending the body from frontend in JSON format. You can use `JSON.stringify()` to encode it.
- Check your browser console and network to confirm the requirements with data to the backend.
- Console the `req.body` to check if there's anything received.